# Wordpress plugin - multiple php files

Tags: plugins

I need help with my first WP plugin. I have php/mysql app splited in 10 php files (mostly some forms) and I have a problem with association between  in formscript.php and that service script (service.php). I certainly need result from service.php in WP (plugin) interface.

Simplified scripts:

```
myfirst.php
<?php /* 
Plugin Name: myfirst
...*/
function myfirst_admin() {
    include('formcript.php');}

function myfirst_admin_actions() {
    add_options_page("myfirst", "myfirst", 1, "myfirst", "myfirst_admin");
} 
add_action('admin_menu', 'myfirst_admin_actions');?>

formscript.php:
echo '<form method="post" action="service.php">
<input type="text" name="something" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>';

service.php:
<?php echo $_POST["neco"];?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please make use of the WYSIWYG editor when adding posts :-)

Comment: I don't understand the question.... everyone has his own coding style. I prefer to have one file if possible, but that is only me. The only thing you need to remeber is to protect your code from direct load, otherwise there should not be a problem with having as many php files as you want.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you shouldn't access your plugin's PHP files directly. By itself file is just a file, it has no way of knowing it is part of WordPress installation. Even purposely loading WP core from arbitrary file is very challenging to do in a generic and reliable way.

What you should be doing is pointing your form at one of WordPress endpoints and using hooks to connect your code to it.

For simple form submission you probably should start with studying [`wp-admin/admin-post.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/4.0/src/wp-admin/admin-post.php) endpoint and trying to make use of it.